# Replacing old well tank that is leaking

Tags: well

I have taken on the task of replacing a well tank for my grandmother. Well I didn’t realize there was this much to the well tanks. I believe she has a air-over water tank. It has an inlet about middle of the tank and the outlet towards the bottom. My question is can I just get a tank for local Lowe’s and just add the tank tee and redirect the plumbing. I’m going add pictures of current setup and then what I was going to buy to replace it with.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your plan is a good one.  I'd remove all that cast iron pipe that I could and replace it with copper.  Be sure to use a dielectric union on the iron/copper connection to avoid corrosion problems.

You'll find that a newer bladder-type tank will not waterlog the way the old air over water ones did.  Be sure, however, that the tank is not in a location that freezes.  Ice in the tank will rupture the bladder.

Comment: Updating galvanized pipe, sure, but PEX rather than copper IMHO.